# Who is it that is looking for Brahmgyan?

Tags: moksha, atma, body, mind, buddhi

My long quest for the Brahma gyan or moksha has led me to a lot of reading, research and meditation and today a question just popped in my mind that seems to be absolutely essential for me to get answered. The question is:
a) WHo is feeling the intense desire to have BrahmaGyan or atmGyan - is it my physical mind, my subtle body/ subtle mind or my soul?
b) If it is physical or subtle body, then when it dies and the Brahma gyan will be lost?
c) If it is my soul seeking the BrahmaGyan then why does it not already have it?

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange website! Fortunately your Qn has already been asked earlier on this website.You can search up on the website and read possibly related answers(eg in case of your first Qn you can search like Who/What attains moksha? is it both mind/atman?Or just the atman?).Then you can attach your research to this Qn and modify it to ask even more specific Qns along with your doubts.Happy reading!

Comment: It is simple - suppose you are in a dream-like state. You see many different people, many different worlds, many different situations. Are any one of them real? No. But if you see a ghost in your dream, you'll get scared, why? Because you **don't know** that you are in a dream that is unreal. Liberation is JUST knowing that you and everything around aren't real. Knowledge of liberation is just for physical and subtile body - so that they can coordinate well with real nature of the universe. It doesn't dies. When the physical body dies, knowledge remains (you wake up from your dream!)

Answer (score 0):

All desires/yearnings, whether they are worldly or spiritual, happen only in the mind of the individual.

In the case of worldly desires, the sense organs first report something of interest and then the mind yearns for it. Lord Krishna explains this in the Gita 2.62

> ध्यायतो विषयान्पुंस: सङ्गस्तेषूपजायते ...

The spiritual desire also arises in the mind of the individual. But this desire arises based on experience. The experience that the world and worldly pleasures can never give me everlasting happiness. From [Mundaka Upanishad](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/mundak/Mundaka_Upanishad.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi875qog5iCAxUYEVkFHeRcDmAQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0A7FAiZrPeWEDyddH2mtrU) (1.2.12)

> परीक्ष्य लोकान्कर्मचितान्ब्राह्मणो निर्वेदमायान्नास्त्यकृतः कृतेन ।
> तद्विज्ञानार्थं स गुरुमेवाभिगच्छेत्समित्पाणिः श्रोत्रियं ब्रह्मनिष्ठम् ॥ १२ ॥

> Let a brahmana (an aspirant), after he has examined the worlds gained by Karma, acquire freedom from all desires,
> reflecting that nothing that is eternal can be gained by Karma. Let him, in order to obtain the knowledge of the eternal,
> take sacrificial fuel (Samit) in his hands and approach that preceptor alone who is well-versed in the Veda-s and is
> established in Brahman.

Since mind is part of subtle body, for your question a) you can say the all desires occur in the subtle body or sukshma shareera.

Now for your question b)

The 2 benefits of Brahma jnanam (moksha) are

1. Jeevan mukti
2. Videha multi

Due to videha mukti, the individual does not have rebirth, so there is no question of losing Brahma jnanam.

(You say you are already doing a lot of reading, so I am not explaining what those terms are as I assume you are familiar with them. If not, drop a note and I'll share more details)

Answer (score -1):

kshetra is eager to meet Kshtragya;
(the incomplete long to meet the rest to get back in state of POORAN).

The **Brahm naad** and **Brahm Prakash** when imbibes in our body (after one crosses a THRESHOLD) then one gets a WHOLE-BODY partner called **BRAHM SWAROOP** or **HARI**.
NOTE; **AVATAR** is the one who is **BORN along with HARI** and perform **BAL-LILA**;
HARI RAMA;
HARI KRISHNA;
HARI SAI RAM;
HARI VITTHAL;
HAR HAR MAHADEVA;
HARI MANDIR SAHIB;
**The disciple imbibes it later IN LIFE (but before death)**
GURU HARI

**Deeper insight**
**Dharama;** the one that takes one into KINGDOM OF BRAHM PRAKASH.

**HARI Dham;**
Kingdom of DIVINE LIGHT or BRAHM PRAKASH or DIVAY PRAKASH.

**Maa/Ma/मा-म** my **BRAHM NAAD** as well as **BRAHM PRAKASH** form.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).